# div in ng-repeat is not getting updated?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, get, auto-update

I am getting a response from http get request and Iam using the response to iterate in the data

```
<div id="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
          <p>{{profile.username}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

---

This is for adding one profile on click

```
<input ng-click="addProfile()" type="button" value="add Profile" />
```

---

Here is my get request in the controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.profiles = [];
 $http.get("test1.json")
 .then(function(response) {
     $scope.profiles = response.data.profiles; //Response is provided below
 });
$scope.addProfile = function(){
      $http.get('test2.json')
     .then(function(response) {
       alert("af");
         $scope.items = response.data.profiles; //Response is provided below
         $scope.profiles.push($scope.items);
         console.log($scope.profiles); //gives the update Array

            });
        });
});
```

---

response of my get request of test1.json

```
{
   "Id": "44442232",
    "profiles": [
        {
           "type": "Friend",
           "username": "Username 1",
         },
         {
            "type": "Student ",
            "username": "Username 2",
           }
       ]
   }
```

---

response of my get request of test2.json

```
{
   "Id": "44442232",
    "profiles": [
        {
           "type": "Friend",
           "username": "Username 4",
         },
         {
            "type": "Student ",
            "username": "Username 5"
           }
       ]
   }
```

I have tried `console.log` after updating in the array.The array is updated but the div in `ng-repeat` is not getting updated?

Comment: your code looks fine, https://plnkr.co/edit/LfnTyxX6Iw3GLcPxRNbf?p=preview

Comment: @Sajeetharan It works fine that way.But you have not written `$scope.profiles` in the `$http get request` that's where the change comes.

Comment: [Here](https://embed.plnkr.co/YIHDBAeIF9v27qbwEXmW/) is working example with $http call

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran That is not working.Can you update it?

Comment: I tested link in FF, Chrome. Which browser you are using?

Comment: What was the error you are getting with the example

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran It is showing `{{profile.username}}`

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran Please see the updated question

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran https://plnkr.co/edit/fJ7evkfWrK04P15riSEQ?p=preview

Comment: The question which you asked initially is totally different from what you have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please close your JSON calling request by putting ')' at the end. There is no error apart from this and the same code works for me fine.
    // Code goes here

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myctrl", function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('test1.json')
 .then(function(response) {
   $scope.profiles = response.data.profiles; //Response is provided below
 });

   $scope.addProfile = function(){
     $http.get('test2.json')
     .then(function(response) {
         $scope.items = response.data.profiles; //Response is provided below
         angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value) {
           $scope.profiles.push(value);
         });
         console.log($scope.profiles);

     });

 };
```

});

Please find this updated js code and check. Once it is fixed let me know. happy coding :)

Comment: Hi, I have seen some plnkr examples in this page. Is that the scenario what you looking for. Since i got updated div in my example.

Comment: can you put the url in which you have seen the examples

Comment: please replace your js file with the code which i posted above. happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think you need **$scope.$apply()** to trigger the digest cycle. You are in angular context.

Second, you are missing a ')' when you are calling **.then()**. You currently have **'.then(function(){};'**

Third, your response object should not have a comma after the username property if that property is the last one in the object.

Also do you have a silent fail, or it is an error in the console, and the processed html for the ng-repeat is blank or you get the angular interpolation syntax {{profile.username}}?

Comment: I have updated the question.please see above and help me to sort this out

Comment: Still missing the ')' on http call. $http.get("test1.json")
 .then(function(response) {
     $scope.profiles = response.data.profiles; 
 }; 
**should be**
$http.get("test1.json")
 .then(function(response) {
     $scope.profiles = response.data.profiles; 
 });

Comment: I have changed.But that was not the problem.